# abap reference variables and dynamic types

Tags: abap

I'm fluent in ABAP and have a grasp on OO and light reference variables, but can't seem to get a deeper handle on reference variables and dynamic types etc.  I've done a bit of reading, but can't seem to get the deep understanding I feel I need.
Does anyone know of some great tutorials or websites that might give clear and concise?  Thanks!

Comment: It's probably worth the question but it's off-topic as per [stackoverflow policy](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic): "Questions asking us to **recommend or find** a book, tool, software library, **tutorial** or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."

Answer (score -1):

First of all just google this post title and You're golden.

Second:
I'm not sure if I understand You correctly, do You want to know about such constructions as:

```
DATA lo_ref_var TYPE REF TO zcl_my_class.
```

And by dynamic types do You mean in ABAP 7.4/7.5 (ex. DATA(lv_var) = 123)?

If yes, I'll try to give You the general idea:
Reference variable is just a variable that's "ready to become" an object.
If You'll take this for example:

```
DATA lo_ref_var TYPE REF TO zcl_my_class.
CREATE OBJECT lo_ref_var.
```

Then assuming the constructor doesn't need any variables You'll get an instance of zcl_my_class Class with all it's attributes and methods. Also if You have an abstract class zcl_abs_class as a super-class and zcl_sub_class1 and zcl_sub_class2 as it's non-abstract subclass' than:

```
DATA:
  lo_abs TYPE REF TO zcl_abs_class,
  lo_sub1 TYPE REF TO zcl_sub_class1,
  lo_sub2 TYPE REF TO zcl_sub_class2.

CREATE OBJECT: lo_sub1, lo_sub2.
lo_abs ?= lo_sub1.
lo_abs ?= lo_sub2.
```

What You can do (as seen above) is cast a subclass object to the super-class reference variable since the subclass' inherits from zcl_abs_class.
For more, do some digging.

Dynamic types:
This is in fact very simple, all You need to remember is that a variable has to have a type when being created dynamically. So for example:

```
DATA(lv_text) = text-000.
DATA(lv_int) = 1.
```

Line with lv_text will not work (will not compile) since text-000 does not have a precise type.
The second line on the other hand will take the type I.
If one would like to decide which type to choose You can do this by writing:

```
DATA(lv_bukrs) = CONV bukrs( '1234' ).
```

You can even use the type that an already existing variable has by writing:

```
DATA(lv_bukrs2) = CONV #( lv_bukrs ).
```

since the "#" means "use the type of variable inside brackets".

Hope this will help You start :)